# How to active data-dismiss after href activated?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have this link

```
<a class='btn btn-danger' href='page.html'>Delete</a>
```

I want to active "data-dismiss" after "href" activated. I have tried this code

```
<a class='btn btn-danger' href='page.html' data-dismiss='modal'>Delete</a>
```

But it does not execute "href" if I use "data-dismiss".
How can both(href and data-dismiss) work?

Comment: onclick of a tag you need to add `data-dismiss='modal'` ? am i right but here href will redirect to another page ?

Comment: @Swati I have tried to add through this `y.setAttribute("data-dismiss", "modal");` But If I set this attribute, href will not be work. So I want that they both should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `button` instead of `a` tag and apply css to button so that it look like `link` . Then , use `attr` to add attribute to your element .

**Demo Code** :

```js
$("button").click(function(){
 $(this).attr("data-dismiss", "modal");//add attribute
 var somecondition=false;
 var href=$(this).attr("href");//get href
 //add some condition if true
 if(somecondition){
 window.location=href;//redirect
 }
 console.log("added")
})
```

```css
button {
  background: none!important;
  border: none;
  color: #069;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn btn-danger' href='page.html' >Delete</button>
```